# NHibernate - does LINQ Where() after Future() trigger query?

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, nhibernate-futures

I have to implement a model based access security on an existing system, to prevent users from loading/changing data from other users. So I created a couple of interfaces for that purpose and made model classes implement them.
I have a base repository class which calls all the queries, so I can check those interfaces only in one place and everything will work.
And it does, but I'm not sure if I broke the Future feature in the meanwhile.

So basically, the question is very simple, if I call this extension method after each Future() call, will it trigger the query immediately (breaking the purpose of future)? Does Where() or casting to interface force Future to execute immediately?

```
internal static IEnumerable<TX> ApplyRestrictions<TX>(this IEnumerable<TX> results, IUnitOfWork uow)
{
    if (typeof(IContextUser).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TX)))
    {
        var currentUser = uow.UserRepository.FindCurrentUser();
        return results.Where(x => (x as IContextUser).User == currentUser);
    }
    if (typeof(IContextCompany).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TX)))
    {
        var currentCompany = uow.CompanyRepository.FindCurrentCompany();
        return results.Where(x => (x as IContextCompany).Company == currentCompany);
    }

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just tested it with Glimpse.
It does **NOT** trigger an immediate query, which is great.